# Найти все вершины орграфа, недостижимые от заданной его вершины

Tags: c++, c

c/c++ Помогите решить,  надо найти все вершины орграфа, недостижимые от заданной его вершины. Граф может быть задан константой, а может быть введён пользователем. Можно использовать алгоритм дейкстры, привёл его ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить обход в глубину или в ширину (DFS, BFS). Если останутся непомеченные вершины - вот они и нужны.

---

Причём тут Дейкстра, и где это "ниже" он приведён? ;)